# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I trying to add a classname into my js code which looks like this

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs');
    for(var i=0 ; i<a.length; i++){
    a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        a[i].classList.add("active");
    });
}
```

it show something like
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined
and my html looks like this

```
<nav>
    <div class="container" id="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#">a</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#">b</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'll be so thankful if someone could help me solve this problem. Muchas gracis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs');
for(var i=0 ; i<a.length; i++){
    a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        this.classList.add("active");
    });
}
```

Comment: I assume OP is trying to add the class active to each `<li>`, this code adds the class active to the `<ul>`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The selector should be `'.nav-tabs li a'`

Answer (score 0):

The function you provide to `addEventListener` uses `this` to address the element itself. So you can simply write:

```
a[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.classList.add("active");
});
```

Also, I think what you actually want is to add it to the `li` or `a` elements instead of the `ul`, so the selector should be the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs a');
```

Also, you probably want to remove the `active` class from the old element otherwise you eventually end up with all element having the `active` class.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs a');
a.forEach(function(e){e.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var active = document.querySelector('.active');
        active && active.classList.toggle("active");
        this.classList.add("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="container" id="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#">link a</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#">link b</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#">link c</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to add the class name to each `<li>` ?

The following will work:

```
var a = document.querySelector('.nav-tabs').children;
    for(var i=0 ; i<a.length; i++){
      console.log(i)
      console.log(a[i])
    a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        this.classList.add("active");
    });
}
```